# Send value from Activity to SharedPreferences in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

How can I send a string value from my `Activity` to `SharedPreferences` in a `BroadcastReceiver`?

If `BroadcastReceiver` is inactive it doesn't send the value.

Comment: what do you mean by 'shared preferences in broadcast Receiver'.  what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need a broadcast receiver for saving to preferences you can do it directly from your activity ? Please describe your problem with more details

Comment: in activity user choose a text and me set it to stringMe. in broadcast i want when a Sms received show a toast and show that stringMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send the String from activity to broadcast receiver to store in a SharedPreference.
Shared Preference will store the value until the application is uninstalled from the device.you can refer android developers or any other website to check how to use SharedPreference.

Comment: i know. i use Shared Preference because user choose this text.